# Procurar o valor do Array B no Array A e retornar os valores do Array A no Array C

Tags: php, array

Possuo dois arrays: `ArrayB` com valores confirmados e `ArrayA` com todos os cadastrados.

Como crio um `ArrayC` procurando os emails do `ArrayB` no `ArrayA`?

```
ArrayA
(
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5c4fa45sdfsd546
            [name] => Fulano
            [surname] => de Tal
            [mail] => fulano@gmail.com
            [phone] => (11) 91234-5678
            [enable] =>  1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5cd2ef021930f40f6455ad1e
            [name] => Beltrano
            [surname] => de Tal
            [mail] => beltrano@live.com
            [phone] => (11) 99876-5432
            [enable] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5cd8s9df89000sdf6455ad1e
            [name] => Cilano
            [surname] => de Tal
            [mail] => cilano@live.com
            [phone] => (12) 99876-5432
            [enable] => 1
        )
}

ArrayB
(
    [0] => cilano@live.com
    [1] => foo.com
}
```

Comment: Cara, o que tu tentaste até o momento? Qual é o problema que estás tentando resolver?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$ArrayA = [
[
    'id'      => '5c4fa45sdfsd546',
    'name'    => 'Fulano',
    'surname' => 'de Tal',
    'mail'    => 'fulano@gmail.com',
    'phone'   => '(11) 91234-5678',
    'enable'  => true,
],
[
    'id'      => '5cd2ef021930f40f6455ad1e',
    'name'    => 'Beltrano',
    'surname' => 'de Tal',
    'mail'    => 'beltrano@live.com',
    'phone'   => '(11) 99876-5432',
    'enable'  => false,
],
[
    'id'      => '5cd8s9df89000sdf6455ad1e',
    'name'    => 'Cilano',
    'surname' => 'de Tal',
    'mail'    => 'cilano@live.com',
    'phone'   => '(12) 99876-5432',
    'enable'  => true,
]
];

$ArrayB = [
    'cilano@live.com',
    'foo.com',
];

$data_via_array_filter = array_filter($ArrayA, function($item) use ($ArrayB) {
    return in_array($item['mail'], $ArrayB);
});

echo "Dados via array_filter\n";
var_dump($data_via_array_filter);

$data_via_array_map = array_map(function($item) use ($ArrayB) {
    if(in_array($item['mail'], $ArrayB)) {
        return $item;
    }
}, $ArrayA);

echo "\nDados via array_map\n";
var_dump($data_via_array_map);
```

NOTA: Se o array for um objeto

```
$data_via_array_map = array_map(function($item) use ($ArrayB) {
    if(in_array($item->mail, $ArrayB)) {
        return $item;
    }
}, $ArrayA);
```

Answer (score -1):

No seu caso, você pode desenvolver um laço de repetição que percorra o seu arrayB, e para cada índice do mesmo, ele fará a consulta para saber se o mesmo existe no arrayA, se existir... Você pode também acrescentar uma posição ao arrayC já setando o valor.

Tente seguir as especificações abaixo e espero que encontre solução para sua dúvida!
Para solucionar seu problema basta realizar um laço de repetição que percorra seu arrayB item a item (Que é o array que contém os dados que você vai validar). Após esse for estar montado, esse valor selecionado vai percorrer todo o arrayA em busca de um match no e-mail. Portanto, criei outro for, que vai percorrer todo o arrayA.
Então, o primeiro for se inicia e entramos no segundo for, pegando o valor do indice e procurando posição à posição do arrayA, se encontrarmos, atribuimos esse valor ao arrayC e posteriormente damos continuidade ao primeiro for, se não encontrarmos damos continuidade diretamente.

Usei sua própria estrutura para ficar de fácil entendimento.

Não sei se expliquei claramente, mas o exemplo vai funcionar na sua máquina, só testar aí!

Precisando estou por aqui!
Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
    <?php

    $arrayA = [
    [
        'id'      => '5c4fa45sdfsd546',
        'name'    => 'Fulano',
        'surname' => 'de Tal',
        'mail'    => 'fulano@gmail.com',
        'phone'   => '(11) 91234-5678',
        'enable'  => true,
    ],
    [
        'id'      => '5cd2ef021930f40f6455ad1e',
        'name'    => 'Beltrano',
        'surname' => 'de Tal',
        'mail'    => 'beltrano@live.com',
        'phone'   => '(11) 99876-5432',
        'enable'  => false,
    ],
    [
        'id'      => '5cd8s9df89000sdf6455ad1e',
        'name'    => 'Cilano',
        'surname' => 'de Tal',
        'mail'    => 'cilano@live.com',
        'phone'   => '(12) 99876-5432',
        'enable'  => true,
    ],
    [
        'id'      => '5cd8s9df89000sdf6455ad1e',
        'name'    => 'Cilano',
        'surname' => 'de Tal',
        'mail'    => 'foo@live.com',
        'phone'   => '(12) 99876-5432',
        'enable'  => true,
    ]
    ];
   
   

    $arrayB = ['cilano@live.com', 'foo.com'];
    $arrayC = [];
   
   for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arrayB); $i++){
        for($b = 0; $b < sizeof($arrayA); $b++){
            if($arrayB[$i] == $arrayA[$b]['mail']){
                $arrayC[$i] = $arrayB[$i];
            }
        }
   }
   
   for($a = 0; $a < sizeof($arrayC); $a++){
       echo $arrayC[$a] . '<br>';
   }
   
?>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).